# qt class using new return non-pointer

Tags: c++, qt

Seeing that QT has a piece of code like this, how can new return an object instead of a pointer?
[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of text, least of all code. Copy-paste text *as text* into your question instead. And where did you get this piece of code from?

Comment: I doubt that you found that within Qt. If it compiles at all, you can find the answer in the definition of the relevant class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made the wrong conclusion. `new` always returns a pointer. You need to read the documentation of the classes you are using to know how their constructor works. One way to enable `foo f = new foo;` is the following:

```
struct foo {
    foo(foo*){}
    foo(){}
};

int main(){
    foo f = new foo;
}
```

Note that `=` here is not assignment! The object `f` is initialized by calling its constructor taking a pointer to a `foo`.